# How to make a description for the help command?

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a Discord bot I made and maintaining and decided to create a better help command. The help command I made for it works but when you give it an argument along with the command (;help ) it doesn't display the description/details. Either I need to refine my code or somehow make it where it shows the description for it.

```
@client.command()
async def help(ctx, args=None):
        help_embed = discord.Embed(title = "Help Command")
        command_names_list = [x.name for x in client.commands]

        if not args:
            help_embed.add_field(
                name="list of supported commands:",
                value="\n".join([str(i+1)+". "+x.name for i,x in enumerate(client.commands)]),
                inline=False
                )
            help_embed.add_field(
                name="Details",
                value="Command not functional. Still working on it!",
                inline=False
                )

        elif args in command_names_list:
            help_embed.add_field(
                name=args,
                value=client.get_command(args).help
                )

        else:
            help_embed.add_field(
                name="Nope.", 
                value="I don't understand what the fuck you are trying to do."
                )
        await ctx.send(embed=help_embed)
```

For the elif, that is where you give the argument for the command wanted to be displayed and described. So how would I give a description for it? Either I need to add something to all of my bot commands or refine the code itself.

Answer (score 3):

define the description at

```
@commands.command(brief="foo", description="this is what u want")
    async def foo(bar):
```

use `bot.get_command("foo").description` to get the description of your command

in your code it's `client.get_command([command_name]).description`

you can try this

```
elif args in command_names_list:
            help_embed.add_field(
                name=args,
                value= f'{client.get_command(args).help}:  {client.get_command(args).description}'
                )
```

or try yourself to fit it in the list value-

```
help_embed.add_field(
                name="list of supported commands:",
                value="\n".join([str(i+1)+". "+x.name for i,x in enumerate(client.commands)]),
                inline=False
                )
```